# Entry point address of a PIE program

Tags: linker, elf, position-independent-code

How do I know the actual entry point address of a PIE program on Linux/Android?

I can read the entry point address using `readelf -l`, but for a elf compiled and linked with `-pie` or `-fPIE`, the actual entry point address will be different from it. How can I get such address at run time? That is, knowing where the program is loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point of a program is always available to it as the address of
the symbol `_start`.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char _start;
int main()
{
    printf("&_start = %p\n",&_start);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and link `-no-pie`:

```
$ gcc -no-pie main.c
```

Then we see:

```
$ nm a.out | grep '_start'
0000000000601030 B __bss_start
0000000000601020 D __data_start
0000000000601020 W data_start
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000600e10 t __init_array_start
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000400400 T _start
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and:

```
$ readelf -h a.out | grep Entry
  Entry point address:               0x400400
```

and:

```
$ ./a.out 
&_start = 0x400400
```

Compile and link `-pie`:

```
$ gcc -pie main.c
```

Then we see:

```
$ nm a.out | grep '_start'
0000000000201010 B __bss_start
0000000000201000 D __data_start
0000000000201000 W data_start
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000200db8 t __init_array_start
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000540 T _start
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and:

```
$ readelf -h a.out | grep Entry
  Entry point address:               0x540
```

and:

```
$ ./a.out 
&_start = 0x560a8dc5e540
                     ^^^
```

So the PIE program is entered at its nominal entry point `0x540` plus `0x560a8dc5e000`.